# How do I obtain the vertices of the current polygon inside a fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've got a shader to procedurally generate geometric shapes inside a quad.  Essentially, you render a quad with this fragment shader active, and it calculates which fragments are on the border of the shape and `discard`s everything else.

The problem is the dimensions of the quad.  At the moment, I have to pass in the vertex data twice, once to the VBO and a second time as `uniform` variables to the shader, so it knows how big of a shape it's supposed to be creating.

Is there any way to only have to do this once, by having some way to get the coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right vertices of the current quad when I'm inside the fragment shader, so that I could simply give the vertex data to OpenGL once and have the shader calculate the largest shape that will fit inside the quad?

Comment: What OpenGL are you using? Desktop GL? OpenGL ES? What version of it?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Desktop OpenGL, writing to an OpenGL 3 context.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want to use a geometry shader. Each vertex would consist of the position of a corner of the quad (a vector of 2-4 values) and the size of the quad (which could be a single value or upto 9 depending on how general you need the quad to be).

The geometry shader would generate the additional vertices for the quad and pass the size through to the fragment shader.

Depending on what exactly you're doing you may also be able to use point sprites and use the implicit coordinates that they have (`gl_PointCoord`). However, point sprites have a maximum size  (which can be queried via `GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE` and `GL_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY`).

Answer (score 1):

You could pull the vertices yourself. You could create a Uniform Buffer or a Texture Buffer with the vertex data and just access this buffer in the fragment shader. In the vertex shader, in order to know what vertex to output you could just use the built-in variable gl_VertexID

Answer (score 0):

I'd pass the top left and bottom right vertices of the quad as two extra input attributes for each vertex. The quads themselves get rendered as triangles.

In the vertex shader, declare two output attributes as flat (so they don't get interpolated) and copy the input attributes to these outputs.